# Bootstrap Responsive navbar that shows a right panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can you help me doing a responsive navbar using bootstrap that behaves like this sample:

http://codepen.io/hanlinC/pen/dJwil

```
//just adding some code to allow me submit the question
```

but aligning everything to the right? An example in codepen/jsfiddle would be much appreciate it.

What I want is that when the "burger" icon is clicked, the same navbar content appears in a right panel with a close icon to close the nav panel.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that sample that works exactly as I needed, and using bootstrap

http://www.bootply.com/nFrEW73dwt#

Thanks.